# Difference between Ruby’s Hash and ActiveSupport’s HashWithIndifferentAccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, activesupport

What is the difference between Ruby’s `Hash` and ActiveSupport’s `HashWithIndifferentAccess`? Which is the best for dynamic hashes?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Below is the simple example that will show you difference between simple **ruby hash & a "ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess"**

- HashWithIndifferentAccess allows us to access hash key as a symbol or string

**Simple Ruby Hash**

```
$ irb
  2.2.1 :001 > hash = {a: 1, b:2}
    => {:a=>1, :b=>2} 
  2.2.1 :002 > hash[:a]
    => 1 
  2.2.1 :003 > hash["a"]
    => nil
```

**ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess**

```
2.2.1 :006 >   hash = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(a: 1, b:2)
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport
    from (irb):6
    from /home/synerzip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.2.1 :007 > require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access'
 => true 
2.2.1 :008 > hash = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(a: 1, b:2)
 => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2} 
2.2.1 :009 > hash[:a]
 => 1 
2.2.1 :010 > hash["a"]
 => 1
```

- class HashWithIndifferentAccess is inherited from ruby "Hash" & above special behavior is added in it.

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby Hash:

```
hash[:key]
hash["key"]
```

are different. In `HashWithIndifferentAccess` as the name suggests, you can access `key` either way.

Quoting official [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) to this:

> Implements a hash where keys :foo and "foo" are considered to be the
>   same.

and

> Internally symbols are mapped to strings when used as keys in the
>   entire writing interface (calling []=, merge, etc). This mapping
>   belongs to the public interface. For example, given:
>
> `hash = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(a: 1)`
>
> You are
>   guaranteed that the key is returned as a string:
>
> `hash.keys # => ["a"]`

Comment: I think in case of HashWithIndifferentAccess,  symbols are mapped to strings when used as keys in the entire writing interface (calling []=, merge, etc). Is it right?

Comment: yes. Internally symbols are mapped to strings when used as keys in the entire writing interface (calling []=, merge, etc). This mapping belongs to the public interface.